# Stop Powershell Pipeline Execution

Tags: c#, powershell

I am executing powershell command synchronously. Binded a eventhandler, which runs successfully when data is emitted by pipeline. When some condition met, i wish to stop powershell command execution, but when i call pipeLine.Stop(), program just hangs indefinitely. May i know what is going wrong?

```
Command shellCommand = new Command("Get-MsolUser");
Pipeline pipeLine = powerShellRunspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeLine.Commands.Add(shellCommand);
pipeLine.Input.Close();
pipeLine.Output.DataReady += delegate(object sender,EventArgs args) {
    try {
        PipelineReader<PSObject> output = sender as PipelineReader<PSObject>;
        if (output != null) {
            bool isCompleted = false;
            while (output.Count > 0 && !isCompleted) {
                PSObject pso = (PSObject)output.Read();
                isCompleted = addDataDelegate(pso);
            }
            if (isCompleted) {
                pipeLine.Stop();                //HANGS HERE
                log("JUST STOPPED PIPELINE..");
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        log(ex.ToString());
    }
    };
pipeLine.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bad idea to stop pipeline synchronously inside the delegate that handles pipeline output asynchronously.

Maybe **Pipeline.StopAsync** method will work better in this code.